# assign permission on DFS server 2012

Tags: permissions, ntfs, file-permissions, dfs

I have 4 directories and 4 groups and I want each group have access to one directory for example GroupA access to Directory A and GroupB access to Directory B and .... . and also I install DFS management and DFS Replication .But i don't know How can i assign permission on directory with DFS .I created namespace on DFS with full permission for administrator and read/write for user but in this situation my scenarios doesn't work because all user has read and write permission and i assigned deny permission on ntfs permission for users but after doing this nobody have access to directory....  my server is 2012 and I realy need help about inherit roles on DFS and NTFS permission after configuration DFS.

thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.) Also, please try to format your question better—using proper capitalization will make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the following:

- Your DFS namespace is \\example.com\shares
- Your DFS points to a local drive E:\shares
- In E:\shares there are two directories, FolderA and FolderB

Permissions for the E:\shares directory are as follows:

- Share: Everyone - Change
- NTFS: GroupA and GroupB - Everything but Write, Delete Subfolder and Files, Delete, Take Ownership, Change Ownership > Apply to: This Folder Only

Permissions for the E:\shares\FolderA directory:

- Inheritance: Disabled > Convert to explicit
- NTFS: GroupA - Everything but Delete, Change Ownership > Apply to: This Folder, Subfolders, and Files

Permissions for the E:\shares\FolderB directory:

- Inheritance: Disabled > Convert to explicit
- NTFS: GroupB - Everything but Delete, Change Ownership > Apply to: This Folder, Subfolders, and Files

OR

You could create a DFS namespace for each group if you want to in this format. \\example.com\groupA, \\example.com\groupB, etc.